# mysql communicate with mssql on different server via php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo, freetds

I have mysql on a linux server which I own having CentOS installed in it. I want to fetch data from another windows server having mssql database.

I need to create a php script that can get the values from mssql server and insert it into mysql server.

I have tried installing FreeTDS also PDO but still I am unable to connect (not sure if I have installed it properly). The error messages I get are Could not Connect to the server and drivers not found.

How can I check if I have installed freetds and PDO drivers correctly.

Basic Diagram of what I am trying to do:

Server A (Mumbai) {Linux Cent OS, FreeTDS and PDO installed} ---------> Server B (Delhi) {Windows, MSSql}

I want to get data from Server B to Server A.

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
62Error 20009 (severity 9):
        Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
        OS error 110, "Connection timed out"
There was a problem connecting to the server

root@server [~]# tsql -C
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: no
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 5.0
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: no
```

How can I update TDS version form 5 to 7

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Configure FreeTDS](http://hugobrowns.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/connecting-to-a-mssql-server-from-linux-centos-6-2-using-freetds-part-1/)

This is a perfect tutorial for configuring FreeTDS. Every thing from basic..superb tutorial.

Thanks to Hugo Brown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the mssql select querys, set a variable in php with the result from the mssql query, and then do a mysql insert query to insert it into your database

```
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'phpfi');
mssql_select_db('php', $link)
$query = mssql_query('SELECT [id] FROM [php].[dbo].[userlist]');
   while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $row['id']
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","pass","db");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tablname VALUES('$id')");
    }
```

Give this a try.
Of course you have to customize it to fit your needs.

Comment: Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: 116.214.26.236

Comment: Tell me if any port is blocking the connection?

Comment: Warning: mssql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource  Warning: mssql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: I have some how configured freetds but its now connecting to port 4000 net.c:205:Connecting to 116.214.26.236 port 4000 (TDS version 7.0)

Answer (score 0):

**Use ADODB Connection**

```
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection", NULL, CP_UTF8) or die("Cannot start ADO");
$connStr = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=myServer;UID=myUser;PWD=myPass;DATABASE=myDB";
$conn->open($connStr); //Open the connection to the database

$SQL="SELECT id, .........................";
$res=$conn->execute($SQL);
while (!$res->EOF)  //carry on looping through while there are records
{
    $id=$res->Fields('id')->value;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php

Now go to Example #2 COM example (2)

Comment: Tried it got the error Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in....tried to uncomment this line ";extension=php_com_dotnet.dll" but I cannot find the line in php.ini

Comment: http://www.clearfoundation.com/component/option,com_kunena/Itemid,232/catid,17/func,view/id,41247/

Comment: I downloaded php_com_dotnet.dll and placed it in ext dir also placed the line extension=php_com_dotnet.dll in php.ini but still the same error.

Comment: I got this COM functions are only available for the Windows version of PHP....i am using linux server....

Comment: @Fakhruddin Ujjainwala use this http://www.clearfoundation.com/component/option,com_kunena/Itemid,232/catid,17/func,view/id,41247/